# How to use fetch to get data from an api

Tags: javascript, json, http, promise, fetch

I'm creating a fetchBill function.
It assigns https://randomapi.com/api/006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c to an api variable.
It uses the browser's fetch function to make a HTTP request to api.
It uses an arrow function in a .then call to the fetch function,and returns the response after converting it to JSON.
Using another .then call to the first one, the function passes the JSON data to displayCartTotal function. Finally, it handles errors that may occur, e.g by showing a warning message in the console.

I've defined the displayCartTotal function as required by the challenge. And it's been verified to be correct.
I've also defined the fetchBill function and it is returning a promise. In the promise, promiseStatus is "resolved", and promiseValue is an Array. I do not get any error, but this does not seem to solve the problem for the challenge.

```
    const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => results;

    const fetchBill = () => {
    const api = 
    "https://randomapi.com/api/006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c";
    const results = fetch(api)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => displayCartTotal(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(`Warning!!! Error fetching data!!! 
        Error ${err}`));
        return results;
};
```

By calling displayCartTotal function, the fetchBill function should return the results property of the json object returned by the fetch request. I believe it's the promiseValue that is to be returned and not the entire promise from the http request.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. What is your exact problem? "does not seem to solve the problem for the challenge" does not help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => results;

const fetchBill = () => {
   const api = "https://randomapi.com/api/006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c";
   fetch(api)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(data => displayCartTotal(data))
   .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for failure of the process is the fact that the Javascript continues after tge promise, and returns the `result` var before the promise process is complete

The simplest way to resolve this is adding thw return into a then:

```
const displayCartTotal = ({results}) => results;

const fetchBill = () => {
const api = 
"https://randomapi.com/api/006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c";
const results = fetch(api)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => displayCartTotal(data))
   .then(return results;)
    .catch(err => console.log(`Warning!!! Error fetching data!!! 
    Error ${err}`));


};
```

Answer (score 0):

The fetch in your case returns the promise, which isn't full filled. Implement the fetch in this type.

```
fetch('https://randomapi.com/api/006b08a801d82d0c9824dcfdfdfa3b3c')
    .then((resp) => {
        if (!resp.ok) {
            if (resp.status >= 400 && resp.status < 500) {
                return resp.json().then((data) => {
                    let err = { errorMessage: data.message };
                    throw err;
                });
            } else {
                let err = { errorMessage: 'Please try again in some time, Server Error!' };
                throw err;
            }
        }
        return resp.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        console.log(data.results[0].buyerCountry);
        console.log(data.results[0].itemsInCart);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Token.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    accessToken = json['access_token'];
    tokenType = json['token_type'];
    refreshToken = json['refresh_token'];
    expiresIn = json['expires_in'];
    scope = json['scope'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['access_token'] = this.accessToken;
    data['token_type'] = this.tokenType;
    data['refresh_token'] = this.refreshToken;
    data['expires_in'] = this.expiresIn;
    data['scope'] = this.scope;
    return data;
  }



 @override
  void initState() {
    Webservice().countryFetch().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        countries = value;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```