# how to access data from simple link with api key through http request

Tags: javascript, blogger, google-api-js-client

I have this simple link
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key

It works fine and give me this

```
{
  "kind": "blogger#blog",
  "id": "##############",
  "name": "blog-blogger",
  "description": "",
  "published": "2022-02-08T08:38:50-08:00",
  "updated": "2022-02-22T16:52:43-08:00",
  "url": "http://original-1-1.blogspot.com/",
  "selfLink":
  "posts": {
    "totalItems": 1
  },
  "pages": {
    "totalItems": 0
  },
  "locale": {
    "language": "en",
    "country": "?",
    "variant": ""
  }
}
```

now how i fetch above data using javascript

like

```
l = fetch(https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key);
q = l.json();
console.log(q.kind);
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016341/how-to-use-fetch-to-get-data-from-an-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you `kind`

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onload = function() {
    let responseJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(responseJSON.kind);
}
xhttp.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something similar this is the code I am using.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', `https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key`, true)

request.onload = function () {
  // Begin accessing JSON data here
  var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
  console.log(data) 
}
```

Another option is using fetch like you suggested

```
function getData() {
  const response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key')
  const data = await response.json()
}
```

This is the website I got my information from:
https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/

Hope this answers your question!

mrt

Answer (score 0):

// declare a variable to hold your API url like this
const url = " [https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key"](https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/my-ID?key=Api_key%22)

```
 // the spelling of your fetch is incorrect. You can use this
```

fetch(url)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));

// this should work

// Using your API key
Ensure you pass your API key into the REST API call as a query parameter by replacing API_KEY with your API key,